# Javascript inline output

Tags: javascript, echo

In javascript suppose you have this piece of code:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">var output = 'abcdefg';</script>
</div>
```

Is there any way to simply "echo" (using PHP terminology) the contents of `output` into `#test`?  That is, to output a string inline, assuming you have no standard way of traversing or selecting from the DOM?

`document.write("...");` does write the contents of `output`, but in doing so, it replaces the entire document with the `output`.

The solution I'm looking for should act the same way a PHP `echo` would: write the output into the document inline.

Comment: 'echo' outputs a string. So, yes, you can use exactly that.

Comment: @DA: `echo` doesn't do anything in Javascript.

Comment: @dclowd: `document.write` does _not_ replace the entire document at all. [It does what you're asking for](http://jsfiddle.net/F6dKz/).

Comment: You are wrong regarding the replacement. Calling it *after* the  DOM was build replaces the content. Calling it during the parsing is fine.

Comment: @dclowd9901: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PREt3/1/). Inline, it doesn't destroy the document.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use the word "inline" if you're just going to use it onload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Kosher" code aside, yes.

`document.write()`

Comment: All this does is replace the whole document with the text you output. This would need to simply insert into the existing document.

Comment: With the caveat that you can't use this after the page loads.

Comment: This is not available in general XML documents, is it?

Comment: @Tomalak, okay, you *can* use it, if you want your page to be replaced with the parameter (which you very rarely do).

Comment: @Matthew: What? [That's not correct at all](http://jsfiddle.net/F6dKz/). Look up `document.write` in your favourite JS docs. [edit: oh, I see what you mean, after the original DOM has finished loading. Well that's OK, the OP isn't asking about that. He's specifically asking about the scenario that works.]

Comment: @jerluc, refer to Matthew Flaschen's comment for clarification.

Comment: Yes, he has a good solution, but I'm confused because you're completely incorrect about it replacing the entire document.

Comment: @Tomalak: http://jsfiddle.net/F6dKz/2/ lols indeed. Assume document.write() is run `onload=`

Comment: For the record, a demo of the [behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/F6dKz/1/) I'm talking about, modified from Tomalak's (EDIT: dclowd9901's is equivalent).

Comment: @dclowd9901: Why would I assume that? You didn't write anything like this in your question. Are you now changing it?

Comment: Hah, so we were all supposed to assume that you wanted it post-load. And it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/F6dKz/3/

Comment: Apologies, Jerluc. I thought I had implemented this correctly already and it wasn't working, but I was running it after document load. You are completely correct.

Answer (score 19):

You'd have to use [`document.write` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write):

```
<div id="test">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write('abcdefg');</script>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/A4L8f/)

With the caveat that it does not work in XHTML documents. See the documentation for more details.

Comment: +1 This is precisely what the OP is looking for (even though solutions such as those posed by Pompom and Matthew would be more advisable).

Comment: The OP already said that he can't use this because it will "replace the whole document with the text you output."  That's exactly what I was warning about, even though I wrote my comment before seeing the OP's.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks. You are right, but in this case the OP specifically asked for this. So I guess it is ok to use in this situation. But apparently not all people really know how it works...

Comment: @Matthew: It is only replacing the whole content if it is called after the document was parsed. As I understood it, this is directly embedded in the HTML so it will work.

Comment: @Felix: I completely agree. My caveat in parentheses was for others reading, not you. :) Notice "even though" rather than "although".

Answer (score 6):

In standards-based browsers:

```
document.getElementByID("test").textContent = output;
```

For broader support, you could use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in jQuery (or the equivalent method if your library of choice):

```
$('#test').text(output);
```

Comment: Yes, this is *an* answer, but I was hoping to find something that wrote inline, in case you didn't have an identifier for the div in question. Allow me to update my question.

Comment: @Dclow: You didn't specify any context for your question. If we assume that you want to modify a generic XML DOM tree, then this sort of approach is your only choice. In the future, provide more background info to get more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Kerrek: The question was quite clear, and Felix managed to parse it just fine.

Comment: As you have alluded, it looks to me like textContent doesn't work in IE6-IE8.

Comment: @Tomalak: OK, the OP says she has no way of selecting from the DOM, but as long as this is a generic DOM question, as opposed to an HTML tag soup one, we cannot assume that `document.write` is even available...

Comment: It's been awhile, but it aught to be `getElementById` rather than `getElementByID`.

`document.getElementById("test").textContent = output;`

Answer (score 2):

You could write something like:

```
<div id="test">
  <script>
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "stuff";
    //this line only changes content in the div with id="test", not the whole dom
  </script>
</div>
```

But you should avoid putting a script inside a div because it may be overwritten.

Comment: Is `innerHTML` available in general XML documents??

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in the div, then `document.write('abcdefg')` is the proper choice for inserting something inline at the point of execution.

Or, if your code is not inside the div, you can do this:

```
<div id="test">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var output = 'abcdefg';
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = output;
</script>
```

You will have to make sure that your code runs AFTER the page is loaded and the div is present.

Comment: Using document.write reloads the entire page and just shows the string

Comment: @blueprintChris - I'd suggest that you write your own question and show your own code.  We can't really help you with seeing your code.  And, please remove the duplicate comments you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if anybody is still looking then here is a handy function that does the job.

```
function echo(text)
{
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log()

http://getfirebug.com/logging

also supported in chrome and ie 9.. watch out for backwards compatibly it will get you ie8 and down i think...

Comment: He wants to put it into the DOM.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen really? i suppose that is why i made the comment above. ;)

Comment: @Kiernan, yes, 7 seconds before mine.  I wonder when I started writing my comment... ;)